# Listen for Container Edges when dragging an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, position

I have an image that is larger than the container that it is shown in. The Image is draggable within the container currently it can be dragged anywhere within the container. I would like to stop the image from being dragged when say the top of the image matches the top of the container.

My Code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        frame = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frame1);


        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

                LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

                Log.d("Alert", imageView.getId() + " pressed");

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams(); 
                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Do Nothing
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    //Do Nothing
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    //Do Nothing
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                }
                frame.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}


 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to stop the image from being dragged further than the borders of its container for example the top of the image should be dragged no further than the top of the layout container.

Answer (score 0):

After a days worth of tinkering with my code i finally came up with working solution to my problem ill post the code here.

```
View frame;
    ImageView imageView;

    //stores position of finger during drag operation
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    //Stores the boundaries of the Frame
    private int frameWidth;
    private int frameHeight;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        frame = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);     

        //Get frame width and height once it has been drawn.
        frame.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // set global variables
                frameWidth = getView().getWidth();
                frameHeight = getView().getHeight();
                //Log.e("Framewidth", "" + frameWidth);
                Log.e("FrameHeight", "" + frameHeight);



            }
        });     

        //ontouch listener that controls the Drag functionality of the keyboard.
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                //get x and y cords of the user touch
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

                LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams(); 
                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Do Nothing
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    //Do Nothing
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    //Do Nothing
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                    Log.e("Test", "" + imageView.getX() + " , " + imageView.getY());    

                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;

                    //stops the outer edges of the image from being dragged past the 
                    //frames outer edges.
                    if(((int)layoutParams.topMargin) >= 1) {
                        layoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                        if(((int)layoutParams.leftMargin) >= 1){
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                        }else if(((int)layoutParams.leftMargin) <= -291){
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = -290;
                        }
                    } else if(((int)layoutParams.topMargin) <= -70) {
                        layoutParams.topMargin = -68;
                        if(((int)layoutParams.leftMargin) >= 1){
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                        }else if(((int)layoutParams.leftMargin) <= -291){
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = -290;
                        }
                    } else if(((int)layoutParams.leftMargin) >= 1){
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                    } else if(((int)layoutParams.leftMargin) <= -291) {
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = -290;
                    }

                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                }
                frame.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is the first part of a larger project to create a custom InputMethod for a Smart watch